# Is there a compilation of device-specific bugs for Android devices?

Tags: android, device

We've found a crash on a particular device that happens inside some of the standard Java libraries.  This crash only happens on one particular model of device.  I'm sure there are other curious oddities for various Android devices.

Is there a compilation of known issues for Android devices someplace?  I'm thinking in particular about oddities in the supplied libraries and JVM type stuff.

Comment: I wish... Android has taught me so much in way of flakeyness, fragmentation and device specific bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware if there is a indexed compilation available on the internet. At the moment, the best place to report/search device-specific bugs is probably still via [Android Issues Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/advsearch), of cause, as long as issues are found and reported  by consumer developer. Actually the search function is not that bad once you are familiar with it.

[HTC Specific Bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=%22htc%20specific%22&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles)

[Samsung Specific Bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=%22samsung%20specific%22&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles)

Device specific bug is a consequence of Android fragmentation, As an Android consumer developer, Our application usually deal with hundreds of different device models. Even the Android award top developer cannot 100% guarantee their application can run seamlessly on all devices. I would not concern too much if the bug is specific for minority device in the market. Nothing is perfect, face the facts.

Comment: As much as I wish there were a better answer, it looks like this is the best we've got for now.  I'm off to see if our particular issue is mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

this is also the problem of the android version, this problem will happen especially in ch, you know, there are a lot of shanzhai telephone. the base android system is changed again and again,as a developer,you can not handle this issue,do as much as you can do is the most important.

Answer (score -2):

That must be difference of OS version. I also got such problem in my application. That application works fine on Desire HD. But crashes on Desire S or Wildfire S.

Then I came to know the version I am using in development was 3.0 or above. But the Desire S and wildfire S have 2.3. and application crashes on these devices.

To identify the problem debug your code in device directly then it will give you Log error.

Hope so this information is helpfull.

Comment: It's the log errors that show me the crash is occurring deep inside the Java Collections library, and it's not a "you used a null key when that's not valid" problem.