# What type of Android apps are the hardest to support (fragmentation worry)

Tags: android, testing, android-virtual-device

Saw an interesting and kinda scary blog post the other day. It was a mobile developer's collection of Android devices they test on. It was around 400. --> http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/0LybOzd0l0U/

I'm a solo guy, there is NO way I could support an app if it took even a fraction of that kind of testing and support. I know you can emulate many devices, but there would still be considerable time in testing on more than a handful of AVDs. It sounds like it could be a nightmare.

For those who've been chewing on Android for awhile, any data or advice on what apps handle the various devices the easiest? The developer in the blog did a lot of games, are those the trickiest?

I'm sure Hello World works very well on all Android devices, but there won't be many takers, you know?

It would be great to know before starting on an ambitious app that for example, GPS is easy, consistent, but native code could be a nightmare, or still pictures are OK, video is nasty to support. SMS, database, sdcard access? OpenGL, gestures, etc. that sort of thing...

If anyone has some general tips or especially an easiest-to-hardest list that could be VERY helpful for us newbies.

Thanks

P.S. and please don't say "develop on iOS...", it's not the question, and worse it's too predictable. ;-)

Comment: This question doesn't belong on stackoverflow. I don't think you'll find anywhere those type of guidelines, you should be more preoccupied on following good android app building rules. Don't start worrying about supporting every device out there until you actually build something that pushes the android platform limits.

Comment: The easiest place to go wrong here isn't so much with different devices as with different versions. As long as you vet the apis you use to be sure that your min/max sdk versions are correct (and stick to documented apis rather than be tempted by hacks), things should go fine.

Comment: Also: http://android.stackexchange.com/ is a better forum for discussing particular devices, SO is targeted for specific programming questions. Also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is good for QA questions and programmer advice.

Comment: possibly the following article can partly answer your question. At the end of the article QA options are mentioned: http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/android-apps-qa#.Ub3-z-d7KSo

Answer (score 5):

They're developing at the `70 million downloads` level and they are pretty big into the Asian market, which means tons of new devices from `lower-end Asian manufacturers`

[Netflix tests on only a dozen or so devices](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/03/testing-netflix-on-android.html), those that represent the majority of their users, some custom ROMs, various processing power and various play-back architectures.

Since it's unrealistic for you to test your device on every single Android device ever made just make sure your app [looks good](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) and is [built solid](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html).

Answer (score 0):

The general advice already given, building something solid and that looks good, is a good starting point. In general the more standalone your app is the easier it is to be confident that it will work on a large number of devices after testing on a core subset of the best sellers.

The main area that gets difficult is when you interact with other apps like Gallery, Address Book, etc. Any place the OEM may/will change the built-in apps that you want to integrate with can cause problems. This is not an issue for most applications. Specifically I worked on a messaging application that required testing on all handsets from a specific carrier; which is not the kind of project I'd expect someone solo to take on anyway.

So the simple answer is avoid integration with other apps, treating it more like the iOS sandbox. Unfortunately that removes some of the Android value but it is the easiest way to avoid fragmentation issues.

Realistically though you do need to test on some real devices if it is important for your to have commercial success with your application. Personally I'd say the minimum for testing would be on handset from each major OEM both Gingerbread and ICS, and if it is a networked app one on each carrier. This level of financial obligation is not realistic for someone just starting, at which point you just end up using your users as testers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you like scary articles, here are 2 other scary (and informative) articles:
http://opensignalmaps.com/reports/fragmentation.php
http://burnsmod.com/development/2012/05/01/Android-Fragmentation-Hurts-Everyone/

As a general rule, anything that uses low level hardware access is a nightmare, so whenever possible, stick with the Java APIs to access hardware functionality.

The camera APIs, whether high level or low level can be problematic. For example I have experienced device-specific issues with the high level camera APIs when invoked via `startActivityForResult` with `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

More info on device specific bugs here:
[Is there a compilation of device-specific bugs for Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792672/is-there-a-compilation-of-device-specific-bugs-for-android-devices)
[Android Device Specific Bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381917/android-device-specific-bugs)

Your best bet is to build for the "normal" devices and then based on the frequency of complaints from users investigate specific devices.